# Function fork()

Tags: c, fork, posix

I have the following code with all the system calls succeed at runtime:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (; argc > 1; argc--) {
    if (0 == fork()) {
        (void) fork();
    }
  }
}
```

I need to find out how many child processes I will obtain.
If I apply one argument the fork() function in fork() == 0 will generate one parent and one child process, and (void) fork() the same => 2 child processes 
If I apply 2 arguments, the number will just be double.
Is it the correct thinking?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: try it out and tell us the answer - a printf of the pid will be useful

Comment: Find out how many child processes I will obtain. Otherwise just a program

Comment: The easiest way is to do a `puts("Malk");` at the end of main() and start it with `./foo | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

using the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (; argc > 1; argc--) {
    if (0 == fork()) {
        (void) fork();
    }
    puts( "mark" );
  }
}
```

here is the result of a few runs with 0, 1, 2 parameters

```
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ ./untitled2 
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ ./untitled2 1
mark
mark
mark
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ ./untitled2 1 2
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ mark
mark
mark
mark
```

notice the problem resulting from the 'race' conditions?

One way to fix the race problem is to `wait()` for all child processes to terminate before starting another set of child processes

I.E.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (; argc > 1; argc--) {
    if (0 == fork()) {
        (void) fork();
    }
    puts( "mark" );
    while( wait( NULL ) != -1 );
  }
}
```

Which results in the very readable:

```
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ ./untitled2 
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ ./untitled2 1 
mark
mark
mark
richard@richard-desktop:~/Documents/forum$ ./untitled2 1 2
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
mark
```